# sending "/" in Meteor http param

Tags: http, meteor

This Meteor server code attempts to use the HTTP package to send a POST request with the `params` object containing date value as below

`orderDate: '03/06/2016'`

```
let params = {};
const d = new Date();
params.action = 'submit';
let day = d.getDate();
day = day < 9 ? '0' + day : day;
let month = d.getMonth() + 1;
month = month < 9 ? '0' + month : month;
params.orderDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + d.getFullYear();

HTTP.call('POST','someurl',{headers: {headerObj}, params: {paramsObj}};
```

How can this "/" be encoded before sending to the remote server as it is responding with `content-length: 0`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In another technology, I found it easier to have your date sent as ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD), unless you specifically need to have day, month and year received as parameters

Comment: The formate the remote server expects is dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: Fixed by setting the params.orderDate = '04/05/2016', i.e. hard code the date. But why?why?why?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changed
`params.orderDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + d.getFullYear();`
to:
`params.orderDate = moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');`

Since the HTTP [docs](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/http/httpcall_server.js#L63)  applies `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to the request `params`, and the two above expressions console.log(d) the same value, that leaves me guessing that the javascript compiler does not treat the output of both expressions the same, maybe in their data types.

If this is the case, how can this issue be best handled when it comes to sending other non alphanumeric characters collected from the client via jQuery..serializeArray() and ends up in the HTTP POST request `params` to a remote server?